# Why the material showing reflection

Tags: texturing, materials

I have assign same material (Glass) to all the Balcony Glass. Why the material showing reflection like a mirror. I have check face are correct. Whats going wrong. Any suggestion. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try lowering the IOR of the Fresnel on your glass shader (closer to 1).

Comment: @ChristopherBennett It work but why the same material show transparent other side and same material show reflection, Any explanation plz

Comment: I'm sorry to say that, but looking at your file you should definitely go through some beginner tutorials, especially on how to use modifiers like the _Array_ modifier and the _Mirror_ modifier... and on Scaling with negative values regarding face normals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your glass have different thickness.

If you lower your thickness (y dimension value) to 0 (as you did with the others) it has no reflection anymore.

[image]

Comment: While making the thickness 0 might work in this particular case, that surely is not the solution for any generic case. Changing a mesh thickness to zero would just risk z-fighting issues. Better to resolve the actual problem (glass materials can certainly have thickness) that just masking it.

Comment: @RichSedman : you are right

Comment: The other glass planes have a thickness of 0 because they are just simple planes with no backfaces. Decreasing the thickness of the glass that has a thickness with a backface to it would not make it the same as the others. And as @RichSedman says, you risk Z-fighting (which wouldn't happen on the single-sided planes).

Answer (score 3):

Most likely a problem with flipped normals. With incorrect normals you'll see 'total internal reflection' where the surface acts as a mirror when viewed from an angle greater than the *critical angle*. Recalculate Normals or manually flip them in Edit mode.

Comment: The normals are alright, at least on the glass object. Although not all of the supporting posts are correct.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the glass material. It's quite a complex setup that I have seen many times before whenever someone had problems with a glass material. If I remember correctly this is the glass setup produced by the Archimesh addon.

I think the purpose of this setup is to make interior renders brighter if lit from the outside by a window, because using the default *Glass BSDF* lets less light pass through thus making the interior darker.

However, quite often this results in unwanted behaviour especially when using (physically correct) glass plates that have a thickness instead of being a single sided plane.

If you simply plug the *Glass BSDF* directly into the material output, the glass is alright. It's still reflecting like glass usually does, but not like a mirror. Notice that the one-sided glass now shows extreme refraction of the object behind, that's due to the Fresnel value which makes the object behind the glass appear as if it was stuck inside a block of glass, because the backside of the glass is missing.

[image: refraction comparison]

If the other glass objects would have a thickness to them like those on the corner, the refraction would be looking correct, too. And notice in this picture that the floor behind the glass isn't darkened as much as with the one-sided glass.

[image: refraction correct]